# How do I use CLI to deploy Security Rules for firestore? Error: Cannot understand what targets to deploy

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, firebase-cli

I can't make the CLI firebase deploy rules work.

I have a file called security.rules at the root level of my firebase project directory.

In CLI, I type:

```
firebase deploy --only firestore:rules
```

Then I get this response in the CLI:

Error: Cannot understand what targets to deploy. Check that you specified valid targets if you used the --only or --except flag. Otherwise, check your firebase.json to ensure that your project is initialized for the desired features.

What I tried:

I tried going into my firebase.json and adding the rules option.

**Before:**

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      //"npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  }

}
```

**After:**

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      //"npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
"rules": "security.rules"

}
```

And I got the same problem... Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command is this:

```
firebase deploy --only firestore
```

Your firebase.json file should have a `firestore` key at the top level, and it may contain two child properties.  When you initialize a new project and activate Firestore, the `firestore` key will be populated like this by default:

```
"firestore": {
  "rules": "firestore.rules",
  "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
}
```

You can modify it if you want to use different file names.

Read the [documentation for firebase.json](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#the_firebasejson_file) for more detailed information.

Comment: For some reason this did not exist in my project.  I think it may be because I transferred this through Git to a different machine.  This worked, thanks.

Comment: To get all this from the outset, you have to select Firestore as a product option when you init your project with the CLI. You probably just didn't select it.